# MVC Saving field data from a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters

I am using MVC and on my Index view I have placed a 'EditorFor' and a 'DropDownFor' fields on it for data entry. I would like a user to enter values and then 'Save' the record from the view. However I am having problems retrieving the data entered. I have tried creating an ActionResult and binding the data however nothing comes across. I have tried giving the fields id names and passing them in as parameters and again nothing is passed.

This is what I have in my View -

```
<h3>Sensitive Areas</h3>
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BurnSitesID, new { @id = "burnSitesID"})
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SensitiveTypesID, "Sensitive Area", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("SensitiveTypesID", string.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SensitiveTypesID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DistSensitiveArea, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DistSensitiveArea, new { @id = "distSensitiveArea" })

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DistSensitiveArea, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    </div>

<input type="submit" id="CreateArea" value="Save"/>
```

How would you take the values entered and pass them to the controller? I have tried a button however if my button is not named the exact same thing as the view it does not do anything.

Comment: is your input elements inside a form ? What is happening when you submit the form ? How does the action method which handles the form submit looks like ?

Comment: You need to use the BeginForm helper or wrap your form with an HTML form element. In the case that you are using Ajax, you should probably show your JS code.

Comment: I added `using (Html.BeginForm())` and it still does not bring across any values. When I submit the form it acts like the fields are empty. That is using the following ActionResult - ` public ActionResult Save([Bind(Include = "SensitiveAreasID,,DistSensitiveArea,BurnSitesID,SensitiveTypesID")] BurnSiteSensitiveAreaIndexData burnSiteSensitiveAreaIndexData)`

Comment: You need to show the relevant information in your question, including the model and the controller methods. (and adding `id` attributes is pointless and has nothing to do with your issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Html.BeginForm("ActionName","ControllerName", FormMethod.Post) .

Button should be Submit type .

If you are use textbox .

```
@Html.TextBoxFor("txtName", "", new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "50" })

<input type="submit" id="CreateArea" value="Save"/>


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionName(FormCollection form)
{
 string Name=form["txtName"].ToString();
}
```

Where Name is a name/ID of field name .

Thanks .

Comment: Thank-you Ronak. This worked exactly like what I was looking for.